# snmptrap and snmptt - authcommunity not found

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to configure snmptt to translate the snmp traps received and handle them as passive checks in an icinga monitoring server as described [here](http://mbrownnyc.wordpress.com/technology-solutions/reliability-monitoring-solution/part-4-sending-snmp-traps-to-icinga/). after doing the changes to the snmptrapd.conf  I am trying to restart the service and I see

```
authcommunity : command not found, traphandle : command not found
```

My understanding is that `authcommunity` and `traphandle` are just configuration directives which will tell snmptrapd about the community string to use and the traphandle script to be called.